# How to discriminate elements from database that have many occurences

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I have a table called ProjectRessources with the following data:

```
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+
| projectId | employeeId | nbHours | wageHours |
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+
| 1         | 1876       | 500     | 65        |
| 1         | 4354       | 2000    | 31        |
| 2         | 2231       | 250     | 55        |
| 3         | 1212       | 3000    | 35        |
| 3         | 1876       | 2000    | 35        |
| 3         | 2231       | 500     | 65
```

I must query the employees that have worked on more than one projects to obtain something like this:

```
+------------+----------------+
| employeeId | nbProjects |
+------------+----------------+
| 1876       | 2              |
| 2231       | 2              |
+------------+----------------+
```

I have tried

```
    SELECT DISTINCT employeeID,projectID
    FROM ProjectRessources
    WHERE COUNT(projectID) >1;
```

but I get an error 1111 on my use of COUNT

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

I have then attempted something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
employeeId ,
COUNT(projectId) as nbProjects
From ProjectRessources
WHERE nbProjects >1;
```

But then I obtain the following error

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'nbProjects' in 'where clause'
```

Please help, any feedback is appreciated. Please note that I am not allowed to use GROUP BY to make my query.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and note that an EDIT button is provided

Comment: The answer that you accepted does not return your expected results.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a second solution that would provide counts without using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try joining the `ProjectResources` table with itself as follows:

```
select distinct p1.employeeID from
ProjectResources p1 join ProjectResources p2
    on p1.employeeID = p2.employeeID and
       p1.projectID <> p2.projectID
```

This just tries to see for each row if there is another row that has the same `employeeID` value but a different `projectID` value. We don't care if how many of them there are as long as there is at least one and that is why we `select distinct` so that the same `employeeID` does not appear more than once (without the `distinct` keyword, we would get one row for every project the employee worked on).

I used the table from your updated question to create an actual table at sqlfiddle.com. Next time you can (and should) do this yourself and post the link in your question.

[See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e56e3c/1)

But this sounds suspiciously like homework.

If you must have the counts:

```
select distinct employeeID, count(*) OVER(PARTITION By employeeID) as nbProjects from (
   select p1.employeeID from
   ProjectResources p1 join ProjectResources p2
       on p1.employeeID = p2.employeeID and
          p1.projectID <> p2.projectID
  ) sq;
```

| employeeID | nbProjects |
| --- | --- |
| 1876 | 2 |
| 2231 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ckpmBGVuGTph15eJomEMa6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You want `having` . . . and the right `group by`:

```
SELECT employeeID
FROM ProjectRessources
GROUP BY employeeId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you want the list of projects, I would recommend `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT employeeID, GROUP_CONCAT(projectID) as projectIDs
FROM ProjectRessources
GROUP BY employeeId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your intervention, however I forgot to add in the question that I am not allowed to use GROUP BY to make my query

Comment: Sorry, I updated the wrong post -- unforgivable.

Answer (score 0):

Without `GROUP BY`, you can do it with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT pr.employeeId,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProjectRessources pr2 WHERE pr2.employeeId = pr.employeeId) nbProjects 
  FROM ProjectRessources pr
) t
WHERE nbProjects > 1
```

If there is a case of duplicate `projectId`s for each `employeeId` change `COUNT(*)` with:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT projectId) FROM ...
```

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ and there are no duplicate `projectId`s for each `employeeId`, you can do it with `COUNT(*)` window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT employeeId,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY employeeId) nbProjects 
  FROM ProjectRessources pr
) t
WHERE nbProjects > 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fff96cb0855178858c4307e73cb11444).
Results:

```
> employeeId | nbProjects
> ---------: | ---------:
>       1876 |          2
>       2231 |          2
```